# zend left join count not working

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, join, count

ia have a problem with count in multi joins

```
$query = $this->select()
        ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
        ->from(array('u' => 'users'))
        ->join(array('c' => 'clients'), 'u.id = c.user_id', 'COUNT(c.user_id) as clientsCount')
        ->join(array('emails' => 'u_emails'), 'u.id = emails.user_id', 'COUNT(emails.user_id) as emailsCount')
        ->join(array('sms' => 'u_sms'), 'u.id = sms.user_id', 'COUNT(sms.user_id) as smsCount')
        ->where('u.id=?', (int) USER_ID)->group('u.id');
```

Comment: I think your problem is that all the counts return the same value?

Comment: yes i have 4 rows in u_emails and 2 rows in u_sms and 2 rows in clients. and all the counts return 16. I dont know where is the problem. It looks like it multiplies.

Comment: It's because you use `Group`. After the group `COUNT` just counts the number of rows returned (which is 16 because there are 16 unique user id's. I think you could easily replace this query with some subqueries.

Comment: How I make the same query with subqueries ? thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can help you out of this problem:

```
$this->select()
     ->from(array('u' => 'users'), array(
            'clientsCount' => new Zend_Db_Expr("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM clients WHERE clients.user_id = u.id)"),
            'emailsCount' => new Zend_Db_Expr("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM emails WHERE emails.user_id = u.id)"),
            'smsCount' => new Zend_Db_Expr("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sms WHERE sms.user_id = u.id)"),
     )
     ->where('u.id=?', (int) USER_ID)
     ->group('u.id');
```

I can't test the query so feel free to ask if you have any problems.

**Edited my answer, please try it again**

Comment: error: call to undefined method query().
how to rewrite in oop as my first example ?

Comment: That has to be done with Zend_Db_Expr. I shall write you a example :)

Comment: @Peet And again I updated the answer :p